# 2016 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Android's [fourth moderator election](https://android.stackexchange.com/election/4) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the 2 new moderators are:

[image: Izzy] [image: Dan Hulme]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://android.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/election/4), or [view a summary report online](http://www.opavote.org/results/4671798641688576/0).

Comment: Congrats to you both, and thanks to everyone who participated.

Comment: Congrats guys and welcome on board!

Comment: Congratulations and condolences to you both.

Comment: Congratz to everyone! Happy Moderator Election!

Comment: Congrats, Izzy and Dal Hulme! :)

Comment: Congrats and welcome to the Moderators section :)